# Boost test : how to debug tested code?

Tags: debugging, testing, boost

I am using Boost test with :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

Tests executions are fine : I can run them, and I can debug them.

But I can't succeed to debug the code tested by Boost Test. I can't enter my function. Note I use the debugger through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I usually 'cop out' by setting a break point:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(For)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(Example)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(HelloWorld) {
     BOOST_CHECK(false);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Then the breakpoint would be at `For::Example::HelloWorld::test_method()`.

An alternative approach seems to be the command line option `--break_exec_path` - but I've never used it